# Не работает цикл в winforms c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Суть моей программы в том что бы при нажатии кнопки появлялся один pictureBox, а в след за ним другой(мерцающий), но при запуске отображается только первый pictureBox

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            pictureBox1.Visible = true;
            Thread.Sleep(10);
            pictureBox2.Visible = true;
            Thread.Sleep(10);
            pictureBox2.Visible = false;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Набираю с телефона, потому за корректность не ручаюсь, но вам надо что то типа такого:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        pictureBox1.Visible = true;
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        pictureBox2.Visible = true;
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        pictureBox2.Visible = false;
    }

}
```